# SumProduct formula Error 13 Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, sumproduct

I m trying to get the sum with multiple criteria:

- "Get" (Column A)
- "Yes" (Column C)
- Sum Column K

As you can see from the image below i manage to get the answer with SumProduct in excel. When i try to get the same answer with SumProduct using VBA i m receveing an error 13 Type Mismatch.

**Image:**

[image]

Any advice?

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Criteria1 As String, Criteria2 As String
    Dim Lastrow As Long, Result As Double
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng1 = .Range("A3:A" & Lastrow)
        Set rng2 = .Range("C3:C" & Lastrow)
        Set rng3 = .Range("K3:K" & Lastrow)

        Criteria1 = "Get"
        Criteria2 = "Yes"

        Result = Application.Evaluate("SumProduct(--(rng1 = Criteria1),--(rng2 = Criteria2),--rng3))")

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Try using `Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct`. Or you could use `SumIfs` instead if you're using a version of Excel that supports it.

Comment: i have try this function getting the same error. Also I get the answer with sumifs  but i want to know what s going wrong with sumproduct.

Comment: The problem is that you're sending the literal text `rng1`, `rng2` etc to the Evaluate function instead of the content of the variable. You could use string concatenation (`SumProduct(--(" & rng1 & " = " & Criteria1 & "), ...`) but you'd end up with a very long and unwieldy string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three things

1. `rng1, rng2, rng3, Criteria1 and Criteria2` are variables. When you put them inside double quotes, they become a string.
2. You have declared `result` as a `Double`. Declare it as a `Variant`. This is causing the mismatch error.
3. The formula you are actually trying is `=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$3 = "Get"),--($C$1:$C$3 = "Yes"),--$K$1:$K$3)`. The criteria should have double quotes around it.

Is this what you are trying? (**untested**)

```
    Result = Application.Evaluate("SumProduct(--(" & _
                                   rng1.Address & _
                                   " = """ & _
                                   Criteria1 & _
                                   """),--(" & _
                                   rng2.Address & _
                                   " = """ & _
                                   Criteria2 & _
                                   """),--" & _
                                   rng3.Address & _
                                   ")")
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. It s working perfectly.

Comment: @Error1004, you might want to let others know that this was helpful by accepting the answer.